# Minimum weight and minimum distance of a linear code

Tags: coding-theory

I got stuck at understanding the solution of an exercise from my coding theory course;

### Question

Show that the minimum weight of a linear code C is equal to the minimum distance of C.

### Solution

Let w be the minimum weight of C and d be the minimum distance
of C. If u $\in$ C, then the weight of u is equal to d(u; 0) by definition, hence w $\geq$ d.
Conversely, let u; v $\in$ C. Then d(u; v) = d(u - u; v - u). Hence d(u; v) = d(0; v - u);
which is the weight of the codeword v - u. This implies d $\leq$ w, and so we conclude d = w.

In the last sentence, How can we deduce that d $\leq$ w??

Comment: What's the distance between the codewords $v-u$ and $0$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your response! hmm, as in the solution, my understanding is that It's the weight (hamming distance to the all-zero-entry vector) of a codeword $v - u$. I can't use it deduce the relationship of d $\leq$ w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's a typo in the question.  You already have $w \ge d$.  For the converse, you need $w \le d$, not $d \le w$.

And, this ($w \le d$) can be seen as follows.  Suppose $d(u, v) = d$, i.e. $u$ and $v$ have the minimum distance.  But $d(u, v) = d(0, v-u)$, which is the weight of the $v-u$ codeword, which cannot be less than $w$.  Hence $w \le d$.